# Magnetic flux through a closed surface

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I was reading Electromagnetic Induction, then I faced a understanding problem while reading the integral and differential form of Faraday's Law..

We know Magnetic Flux= ${\bf B} \cdot {\bf S}$

Where ${\bf B}$ is Magnetic field and ${\bf S}$ is the area it is passing through.

But while considering a small area in that surfac it is usually written that the total **magnetic flux** = **Integration of B.ds**, instead of **dB.ds**, I am wondering how it is taking B as constant...why can't I say total flux is integration of small magnetic field in that area * the small area ?

Comment: It's the magnetic field at that point "times" the small area. B can be different at different locations.

Answer (score 0):

The differential form $\mathbf {B.dS}$ doesn't mean that $\mathbf B$ is constant. It is like the differential form for the work: $dw = \mathbf {F.dr}$, where $\mathbf F$ is not necessarily constant along the path.